# How to set custom activity for discord.js bot in version 14?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to set a custom activity for my discord bot without using any of the predefined types such as **Playing, Watching, Listening**, etc. I used the correct types according to the documentation but I can't seem to figure out why the custom status will not show anything for the bot.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require ('discord.js');
const client = new Client ({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.GUILDS] });

client.on ('ready', () => {
  console.log (`Logged in as $ {client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setPresence ({
    activities: [
      {
        name: 'Custom status',
        type: ActivityType.Custom,
      },
    ],
    status: 'online',
  });
});

client.login ('token');
```

I have tried using Playing and it works just fine.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require ('discord.js');
const client = new Client ({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.GUILDS] });

client.on ('ready', () => {
  console.log (`Logged in as $ {client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setPresence ({
    activities: [
      {
        name: 'Random Game',
        type: ActivityType.Playing,
      },
    ],
    status: 'online',
  });
});

client.login ('token');
```

Comment: I don't think bots can have custom statuses.

Comment: I would assume there's no workaround it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import it from discord.js:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require('discord.js');
```

And set like this

```
client.user.setPresence({
  activities: [{ name: `discord.js v14`, type: ActivityType.Watching }],
  status: 'Hello world',
});
```

I use it and work XD